# Youtube API - Rating - Python

Tags: python-2.7, youtube-api, rating

How can I retrieve the number of Likes or Dislikes of a video using Python?

The entry.rating element will show me:

```
<ns0:rating xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" average="4.936976" max="5" min="1" numRaters="101501" rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#overall" />
```

Which according to [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_ratings), is a deprecated element

```
<gd:rating>
```

but I don’t know how to use the new element

```
<yt:rating>.
```

Can someone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: You should start looking at version 3, https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

Answer (score 1):

you can use pafy api

http://np1.github.io/pafy/

```
import pafy
url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMt47wvK6u0"
video = pafy.new(url)
print video.likes
print video.dislikes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Data API v3 instead.

[videos->rate](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate) and [videos->getRating](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/getRating) are your calls.

You can use [Python library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/) and checkout [Python code samples](https://github.com/youtube/yt-samples-python).